# How to find the IP address of the interface connected to the Internet on a Cisco device?

Tags: networking, router, ip-address, network-interface

I have to subnet the Class B network of `128.0.0.0`.

I have already done the subnetting, but when writing out the interface IP addresses, I have no idea what that is for the router's interface connected to the internet.

Here's my current cisco diagram:

[image: Cisco diagram]

In this case, it is the S0/0 interface for the Seoul router. I managed to find the IP addresses for the other interfaces based on the subnets for the WANs and LANs, but I have no idea how I should go about finding the IP address for the interface connected to the Internet.

A friend suggested that I use one of my spare /30 subnets for the Seoul S0/0 interface. Would that be the correct method?

Comment: What do you mean by "finding the IP address"? Is this an exam question or a real network? The IP address for the interface connected to the Internet is whatever is provided by the next hop (the ISP).

Comment: It is an assignment question. We have to subnet the network given, create a cisco network diagram and write out all the interface names and their IP addresses. If the address is based on the next hop, does that mean there won't be a fixed IP address for that interface?

Comment: That depends on how the ISP is assigning IP addresses. It could be a fixed IP address. You have to ask the ISP ;)